# <http> and <authentication-manager> tags are not working in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My spring security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true"> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" /> 
    </http> 
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="suvajit" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

i am using

```
org.springframework.security.config-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.security.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
```

for spring security..

It is giving me compilation error

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'authentication-manager

and multiple annotations found at this line:

- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/
   spring-security-3.2.xsd', because

  1. could not find the document;
  2. the document could not be read;
  3. the root element of the document is not .
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.

for authentication-manager and http tags respectively

please clarify me where i am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jars are

- org.springframework.security.config-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.security.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.security.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar

But your xml document references version 3.2 - make them compatible, by upgrading your jars to 3.2.3 RELEASE version.

Comment: hi NimChimpsky :: i have already done that. i have changed it to 3.0 and also have done vice- versa. I have tried this by adding 3.2 jars with 3.2 xsd.. Still this is not working..

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd

I have added this in place of 3.2 xsd but still not working

Comment: namespsace 3.2 works with the version of the jars I referenced. Maybe you did not update yours correctly. Are you using maven, do a clean build first.

Comment: the error is quite specific "could not find the document" the compiler can't find the reference/jars. You sure your classpath is correct ? Are you using maven?

Comment: i am not using maven.. just creating this project from eclipse.. i have my jars in lib folder of web-inf in my project directory..